# how to parse json which has key's value inside string with aray

Tags: json, string, flutter

this is the json i want to parse

```
{ "vendorcategory": [
            {
                "id": "ctg-1",
                "_cO": 1598431685530,
                "_dL": 1,
                "name": "Fruits & Vegetables",
                "value": "[ { \"id\":\"ctg-1A\", \"name\":\"Fresh Vegetables\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\", \"value\":[ {\"id\":\"ctg-1A-1\", \"name\":\"Potato, Onion, Tomato\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1A-2\", \"name\":\"Leafy Vegetables\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1A-3\", \"name\":\"Root Vegetables\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1A-4\", \"name\":\"Cucumber & Capsicum\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1A-4\", \"name\":\"Cabbage & Cauliflower\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1A-5\", \"name\":\"Beans, Brinjals & Okra\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1A-6\", \"name\":\"Gourd, Pumpkin, Drumstick\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1A-7\", \"name\":\"Specialty\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" } ] }, { \"id\":\"ctg-1B\", \"name\":\"Herbs & Seasonings\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\", \"value\":[ {\"id\":\"ctg-1B-1\", \"name\":\"Lemon, Ginger & Garlic\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1B-2\", \"name\":\"Indian & Exotic Herbs\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" } ] }, { \"id\":\"ctg-1C\", \"name\":\"Fresh Fruits\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\", \"value\":[ {\"id\":\"ctg-1C-1\", \"name\":\"Mangoes\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1C-2\", \"name\":\"Bananna, Sopota & Papaya\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1C-3\", \"name\":\"Apples & Pomegranate\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1C-4\", \"name\":\"Kivi, Melon, Citrus fruit\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1C-5\", \"name\":\"Seasonal Fruits\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1C-6\", \"name\":\"Fruit Baskets\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" } ] }, { \"id\":\"ctg-1D\", \"name\":\"Exotic Fruits & Veggies\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\", \"value\":[ {\"id\":\"ctg-1D-1\", \"name\":\"Exotic Fruits\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1D-2\", \"name\":\"Exotic Vegetables\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" } ] }, { \"id\":\"ctg-1E\", \"name\":\"Organic Fruits & Vegetables\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\", \"value\":[ {\"id\":\"ctg-1E-1\", \"name\":\"Organic Vegetables\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1E-2\", \"name\":\"Organic Fruits\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" } ] }, { \"id\":\"ctg-1F\", \"name\":\"Cuts & Sprouts\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\", \"value\":[ {\"id\":\"ctg-1F-1\", \"name\":\"Cut & Peeled Veggies\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1F-2\", \"name\":\"Cut Fruits, Tender Coconut\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" }, {\"id\":\"ctg-1F-3\", \"name\":\"Fresh Salads & Sprouts\", \"iKey\":\"Blobkey\" } ] } ]"
            }
        ]}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Use jsonDecode from dart:convert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the dart solution. You can use @Arty's concept.

If you notice `value` is actually a string.

so you can parse the whole JSON first, then from the value variable parse it again.

So, here is the first Data model for parsing first JSON

```
import 'dart:convert';

Category categoryFromJson(String str) => Category.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String categoryToJson(Category data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Category {
    Category({
        this.vendorcategory,
    });

    List<Vendorcategory> vendorcategory;

    factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Category(
        vendorcategory: List<Vendorcategory>.from(json["vendorcategory"].map((x) => Vendorcategory.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "vendorcategory": List<dynamic>.from(vendorcategory.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Vendorcategory {
    Vendorcategory({
        this.id,
        this.cO,
        this.dL,
        this.name,
        this.value,
    });

    String id;
    int cO;
    int dL;
    String name;
    String value;

    factory Vendorcategory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Vendorcategory(
        id: json["id"],
        cO: json["_cO"],
        dL: json["_dL"],
        name: json["name"],
        value: json["value"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "_cO": cO,
        "_dL": dL,
        "name": name,
        "value": value,
    };
}
```

Now Category class contains Vendorcategory items. And Vendorcategory contains the second JSON in `value` variable.

Here is the second Data Class for the second JSON

```
List<ValueItem> valueItemFromJson(String str) => List<ValueItem>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => ValueItem.fromJson(x)));

String valueItemToJson(List<ValueItem> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class ValueItem {
    ValueItem({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.iKey,
        this.value,
    });

    String id;
    String name;
    String iKey;
    List<ValueItem> value;

    factory ValueItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ValueItem(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        iKey: json["iKey"],
        value: json["value"] == null ? null : List<ValueItem>.from(json["value"].map((x) => ValueItem.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "iKey": iKey,
        "value": value == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(value.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}
```

Now call this function

```
var ven = category[0]
List<ValueItem> = valueItemFromJson(ven.value)
```

you will get value list items.

Happy coding

Comment: Don't know dart, but it looks like it has only static types? So you can't say just `object = json.parse(string)` and get full object with nested things out of json? Like one line in Python code.

Answer (score 0):

My next solution is in Python language, didn't notice at first that it is not a Python question, still my simple script can be used if you just need one-time conversion of your files.

You can use next code to re-convert your input json file to output json file while converting value from string to object.

Also before using next script you have to be sure that your input file is a valid json, [this site](https://jsonlint.com/) can be used to find and fix syntax errors in input json file.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64281272#main.py) (Look for `output.json` resulting file on left pane, also `input.json`).

```
import json

with open('input.json', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    obj = json.loads(f.read())
    
obj['vendorcategory'][0]['value'] = json.loads(obj['vendorcategory'][0]['value'])

with open('output.json', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(obj, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False))
```

Example conversion resulting output:

```
{
    "vendorcategory": [
        {
            "id": "ctg-1",
            "_cO": 1598431685530,
            "_dL": 1,
            "name": "Fruits & Vegetables",
            "value": [
                {
                    "id": "ctg-1A",
                    "name": "Fresh Vegetables",
                    "iKey": "Blobkey",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1A-1",
                            "name": "Potato, Onion, Tomato",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1A-2",
                            "name": "Leafy Vegetables",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1A-3",
                            "name": "Root Vegetables",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1A-4",
                            "name": "Cucumber & Capsicum",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1A-4",
                            "name": "Cabbage & Cauliflower",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1A-5",
                            "name": "Beans, Brinjals & Okra",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1A-6",
                            "name": "Gourd, Pumpkin, Drumstick",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1A-7",
                            "name": "Specialty",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "ctg-1B",
                    "name": "Herbs & Seasonings",
                    "iKey": "Blobkey",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1B-1",
                            "name": "Lemon, Ginger & Garlic",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1B-2",
                            "name": "Indian & Exotic Herbs",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "ctg-1C",
                    "name": "Fresh Fruits",
                    "iKey": "Blobkey",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1C-1",
                            "name": "Mangoes",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1C-2",
                            "name": "Bananna, Sopota & Papaya",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1C-3",
                            "name": "Apples & Pomegranate",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1C-4",
                            "name": "Kivi, Melon, Citrus fruit",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1C-5",
                            "name": "Seasonal Fruits",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1C-6",
                            "name": "Fruit Baskets",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "ctg-1D",
                    "name": "Exotic Fruits & Veggies",
                    "iKey": "Blobkey",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1D-1",
                            "name": "Exotic Fruits",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1D-2",
                            "name": "Exotic Vegetables",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "ctg-1E",
                    "name": "Organic Fruits & Vegetables",
                    "iKey": "Blobkey",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1E-1",
                            "name": "Organic Vegetables",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1E-2",
                            "name": "Organic Fruits",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "ctg-1F",
                    "name": "Cuts & Sprouts",
                    "iKey": "Blobkey",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1F-1",
                            "name": "Cut & Peeled Veggies",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1F-2",
                            "name": "Cut Fruits, Tender Coconut",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "ctg-1F-3",
                            "name": "Fresh Salads & Sprouts",
                            "iKey": "Blobkey"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think he is looking for the solution in dart not python

Comment: @ShudiptoTrafder Just noticed that. Sorry. I instructed StackOverflow to show me python questions, but somehow this non-python came up without me noticing this. But still if he just needs one-time conversion my Python solution can be appropriate too.

Comment: @ManuSingh Welcome! ;)